# Pass params from one state to another not releated state with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, parameters, angular-ui-router

According to the ui-router wiki [stateParams](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha) it is possible to pass params from one state to one other. My issue is that while in the example the state are in someway related in my case the two state aren't related but they belong to two different angular modules.  is it still possible to pass the params in someway?

```
function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('login', {
          url: '/login?id',
          templateUrl: 'modules/login/partials/login.html',
          controller: 'LoginController',
          resolve: {
            userId: ['$stateParams', function($stateParams) {
              return $stateParams.id;
            }]
          }
}
```

---

```
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('canvas', {
          url: '/canvas',
          templateUrl: 'modules/canvas/partials/canvas.html',
          controller: 'CanvasController'
        });
    }
```

in the canvas controller the userId is `undefined`

Comment: it doesn't make sense, where you are requesting the user id in canvas controller / route definition?

Comment: You need to use a service which is acts as a session, to hold the user id and get it from the session service.